# Please how do i sum up all the integer elements from a sqlite3 table row

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to calculate the sum total of the elements of a row using user data from a sqlite3 database table

i used cursor.fetchall() to get the amount row in my database table and tried using the for loop to sum the elements of the table but i am getting an error

```
db = sqlite3.connect('my.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT amount FROM expenses')
result = cursor.fetchall()
c = 0
for x in result:
    c += x
print(c)
```

i got
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'
i expected to get the sum total of the amount

I am aware of the sqlite3 SUM command. But I would like to learn how to solve this problem using Tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use builtin `sum()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum)) function from Python:

```
c = sum(i[0] for i in result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
c = 0
for x in result:
    c += x[0]
```

`cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples, with the tuple containing the column values per row. In your case, there happens to be only one column, but it's still a (one element) tuple.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know cursor.fetchall() returns a tuple (like your error tells you) that means all your selections of the sql query will be pushed into that tuple.

For example if you want to select multiple columns:

```
'SELECT amount, tax, date FROM expenses'
```

you will retrieve a tuple like this:

```
(amount, tax, date)
```

This tuple is given for every row. In your case result is an array containing a all rows, where each row itself is a tuple with just the amount in it.

To keep a long story short you either need to rebuild the result as a list with list comprehension for example:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT amount FROM expenses')
result = cursor.fetchall()

result = [amount[0] for amount in result] # Rebuild your result array to contain 
                                          # single values instead of tuples
c = 0
for x in result:
    c += x
print(c)
```

Another solution would be:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT amount FROM expenses')
result = cursor.fetchall()
c = 0
for x in result:
    c += x[0] # This will retrieve the 0th element from the tuple, which is the amount
print(c)
```

Comment: "cursor.fetchall() returns a tuple": actually, it returns a list of tuples.